# cannot use the image inside the storybook

Tags: reactjs, image, storybook

I tried to use the images in the storybook. that image also inside the storybook project only.
Here is my storybook **webpack.config.js** file.
const path = require('path');

```
module.exports = async ({ config }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(sass|scss)$/,
        use: ['resolve-url-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
    });
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            query: {
                name: '[name].[ext]'
            }
        }
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
    });

    return config;
};
```

this is how I import the images

```
import arrow from '../../static/arrow.png';
```

I got the image source like

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,ZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgX193ZWJwYWNrX3B1YmxpY19wYXRoX18gKyAiQmFubmVyV2Vla2VuZDIucG5nIjs=" alt="test">
```

Comment: https://github.com/artyomDev/react-story-book

Comment: it is not working @ArtemMedianyk